All ImageViews Drawables have same color after using mutate() - Why?
This works perfectly fine (different color according to "shared"):
while() {
    ImageView iv = new ImageView(requireContext());
    iv.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_share);
    if(shared > 0) {
        ImageViewCompat.setImageTintList(iv, ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#000000")));
    }
}

All ImageViews have same color (same as the last ImageView):
while() {
    ImageView iv = new ImageView(requireContext());
    iv.setImageDrawable(IconsCache.whatever.mutate());
    if(shared > 0) {
        Log(black);
        ImageViewCompat.setImageTintList(iv, ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#000000")));
    } else {
        Log(white);
        ImageViewCompat.setImageTintList(iv, ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#ffffff")));
    }
}

Why on earth is that even possible when I'm using mutate()?

mutate() is a little confusing. It doesn't create a new Drawable instance; it tells the current instance to start tracking its internal state separately. That cache setup looks like it's setting the same Drawable instance on every ImageView, and you just keep calling mutate() on that one instance over and over.
